# split comma separated emails into different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of data for a group of users in a table. The data is in JSON format and I have to extract it from there.

There is a data set, emails which contains multiple emails of that user. Some users have 4 emails while others have 3,2,1 or even none.

The data is in the form:

```
{"androidId":"49ca9d8934c67a03","deviceId":"863177039120979","emails":"xyzabcdef123@gmail.com,helloworld56@gmail.com,ihaveemail@gmail.com,gojkl8823@gmail.com","manufacturer":"LENOVO","name":"Lenovo A6020a40","networkOperator1Id1":"405854"}
```

So firstly I am extracting this data from JSON and I get the result as

```
emails:xyzabcdef123@gmail.com,helloworld56@gmail.com,ihaveemail@gmail.com,gojkl8823@gmail.com
```

**But now I need to separate out these emails into columns accordingly.**

Here, the final table should look like

- email1 : xyzabcdef123@gmail.com
- email2 : helloworld56@gmail.com
- email3 : ihaveemail@gmail.com
- email4 : gojkl8823@gmail.com

I have tried some things but not getting there. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, because it seems more likely to be "accidental".  However, you should confirm the database you are really using.

Comment: Are you sure you want columns? Returning as columns will limit you to a set number of entries

Comment: I was thinking columns would make it easier for me to read and analyse the data, plus i would need to match the email with some other columns.

Comment: I recommend to transform the json data before importing it to BigQuery. Maybe use Dataflow or Dataprep.

Answer (score 0):

Try string_Split function

```
select STRING_SPLIT ( Emailcolumn , ',')  from email
```

ex

```
DECLARE @emails NVARCHAR(400) = 'me@aol.com,you@prodigy.com,him@zebra.net,that@compuserve.com,her@juno.com'  

SELECT value  as EmailAddress
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@emails , ',')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Comment: Gives an Error: Function not found: STRING_SPLIT

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is a system Function, what version of SQL server you using?

Comment: I am using BigQuery here